# How to save multiple monitor layout forever with xrandr?

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I have two monitors, and set up a new layout by typing following code in terminal:
`xrandr --output HDMI-2 --left-of eDP-1 --auto`
However the layout will go back once wake up from hibernate or reboot. And I have installed a GUI controller named `arandr`. But it cannot solve my problem either, so what is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put your xrandr command in autostart. I use LXDE so I'm unfamiliar with where this functionality is in stock Ubuntu but I'm sure it's there somewhere.